# Textbox will not accept if you input first a " "

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 question. First,  i have a `TextBox` named `Student Name`. My problem is that when i press <kbd>Space</kbd> the value in my `TextBox` will be `" "`. And then when i press <kbd>Save</kbd> button it save in my DB.

Well the condition I make in my textbox is it will not save if theres no text but since it has a value `" "` its accepted. And the second is that you must not input `"space first before letter"`. Example if you enter `" John"` it will display a message that  says: `"Theres no name that starts with space!"` well something like that ...

Answer (score 0):

This simple if loop will do nothing if `Textbox1` is  `" "`, it will warn you if the text is just a space and otherwise it will perform an action

```
Private Sub SaveBtn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveBtn.Click

    Dim _string As String = TextBox1.text
    If _string = " " Then
        ' do nothing
    ElseIf _string.Substring(0, 1) = " " Then
        MessageBox.Show("Theres no name that starts with space!")
    Else
        'save to database code
    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `Trim()` function for that.

```
yourTextBox.Text.Trim()
```

You can use the following code:

```
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text.Trim()) Then
        'incorrect input
    Else
        'correct input
    End If
```

I suggest that you don't come back to server only to say that the first character cannot be a space. You simply use the `Trim()` function and remove the leading as well as trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
'check for empty strings or only whitespace
if string.isnullorwhitespace(textbox1.text) then
    Messagebox.show("You have entered a blank name")

elseif textbox1.text(0) = " " then 'First letter is a space
    Messagebox.show("Theres no name that starts with space!")
else
    'all requirements have been met, put your update to database code here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just automate it like this so every input will be corrected even space at the end

```
    If TextBox1.Text.Trim(" ") = String.Empty Then
        MessageBox.Show("You have entered a blank name")
    Else
        Dim inputstring As String = TextBox1.Text

        inputstring = TextBox1.Text.TrimEnd(ControlChars.NewLine.ToCharArray)
        inputstring = inputstring.TrimStart(" ")
        inputstring = inputstring.TrimEnd(" ")
        inputstring = inputstring.Replace(vbNewLine, " ")
        TextBox1.Text = inputstring
    End If
```

this works in single and multiline textbox